# If $K$ is a Field, $j$ is a field isomorphism, $f$ is a field monomorphism what could be the meaning of $f|_K=j$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

If $K$ is a Field, $j$ is a field isomorphism, $f$ is a field monomorphism what could be the meaning of $$f|_K=j \  ?$$

Answer (score 0):

The notation $f|_K$ is used when $K$ is a subfield of another field $L\supseteq K$ and $f:L\to F$ is a field homomorphism of $L$ into a field $F$.
Then $f|_K$ is the restriction of $f$ to $K$, that's the field homomorphism defined by:
$$f|_K:x\in K\mapsto f(x)$$